# Handlebars helper dependencies

Tags: ember.js

My question is based on [Ember handlebars dependencies documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_dependencies), and in partiuclar on the following code example:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fullName', function(person) {
     return person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
}, 'firstName', 'lastName');
```

I'm glad that there is an easy way to list dependencies when creating the helper, but my question is: **how does Ember know which object on which to look up those properties**?

From the example it's clear that it will be looking on the object passed as the first parameter to #helper (i.e. `person`), but this is a special, simple case. What if I passed multiple objects to the helper?

By the way, I'm aware that I could be super explicit by using this.observes(obj, 'prop'), but I'm just wondering how the convenience method works.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it is not documented for helpers, however it is analogical to [COMPUTED PROPERTIES AND AGGREGATE DATA](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)

You can use the above convention like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('allFullNames', function(people) {
     return myFunctionToGetAllNames(people);
}, '@each.firstName', '@each.lastName');
```